# How do I keep table data elements from merging into one column?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am loading API data into a `table` using Flask and once the elements are placed in their cells, I have jQuery to add bootstrap class to the `td` elements. When I add bootstrap classes `"btn"` and `"btn-secondary"`, the two td elements are sticking side by side where as I want them in their respective columns.

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    {% for row in values %}
    <tr class="item">
      <td class="link"><a href="#">Link</a></td>
      {% for element in row['values'] %}
      <td>{{ element }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The for loops are jinja templating to substitute the values into the table

```js
$(".item td:nth-child(7)").addClass("requestedStatus btn btn-secondary");
$(".item td:nth-child(7)").on('click', function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text() == 'IN' ? 'OUT' : 'IN');
})

// Add button feature and Toggle text between True and False for usageFlag column 
$(".item td:nth-child(8)").addClass("usageFlag btn");
$(".item td:nth-child(8)").on('click', function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text() == 'True' ? 'False' : 'True');
})
```

[image: Image screencap]

Please assist me on this.

Comment: Please show us the structure that you have

Comment: Edited to add the table structure